# Is Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 an update to Visual Studio Express 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Is `Visual Studio 2013 Update 2` an update to `Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop`?

Can an update that is not `Express` and not specific to `Windows Desktop` be appropriate for the `Express` specific and `Windows Desktop` specific product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is the link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2927432) for the Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

According to the website, Update 2 is meant to update all Visual Studio 2013 programs including Express.